# CSS: Put list of buttons horizontally within a div

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm trying to put a list of buttons side by side so they all fit into a wide-but-short bar. My code worked when the list of buttons was instead a list of image links, but changing them into actual buttons displaced them. Now they're off to the top and right.

Oddly after temporarily giving the ul a background color, it seems the ul is still inside the div--it's an issue of rogue list items. What's going on?

My XHTML:

```
<div class="accent-bar">
    <ul class="accents">
        <li id="first"><input type="button" name="a" id="a" value="&aacute;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="e" id="e" value="&eacute;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="i" id="i" value="&iacute;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="n" id="n" value="&ntilde;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="o" id="o" value="&oacute;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="u" id="u" value="&uacute;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="umlaut" id="u" value="&uuml;" /></li>
        <li><input type="button" name="?" id="?" value="&iquest;" /></li>
        <li id="last"><input type="button" name="!" id="!" value="&iexcl;" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.accent-bar {
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: #000000 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;
    }
    ul .accents {
        list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul.accents li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: 5px;
            }
            ul.accents li#first {
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
            ul.accents li#last {
                margin: 1px 0 0 15px;
}
```

Comment: A picture showing what you currently see and what you expect would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works just fine in Chrome, with the buttons laid out horizontally.
In IE, however, it comes out vertically like you say.
I changed the `display: inline-block;` to `display: inline;` and it now works in IE just like in Chrome.

Would that work for you?

**EDIT:**
To make it align to the left edge:
Firstly, make sure you correct `ul .accents` to `ul.accents` (remove the space).
Secondly, to remove that left-side indentation, give that class `padding: 0px;` and it should work.

As for the vertical alignment, I'm not really sure what's missing here -- it's one line, there's no space above or below it to align within.  Could you clarify this part?

Comment: This does place them horizontally in both browsers, but they're still not placed properly. They should be centered vertically and start at the left within the box, and it seems that no matter how I play with the margins or positioning, I can't get that to happen.

Comment: Good catch with the ul. I posted my own answer, but you pointed me in the right direction so I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured out that I needed to specifically target the first button itself for the buttons to move properly. NOT the containing list item; the button itself.

Trying to give all the buttons negative left margins effectively reversed them, but giving just the first one makes the rest move appropriately. Here's the code I'm using now:

```
.accent-bar {
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: #000000 1px solid;
    border-bottom: #000000 1px solid;
    }
    ul .accents {
        list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul.accents li {
            display: inline;
            margin-left: 15px;
            }
            ul.accents li#last {
                margin-right: 15px;
                }
                ul.accents li#first input {
                    margin-top: 18px;
                    margin-left: -250px;
}
```

Comment: @user460847 -- I appreciate accepting my answer, but if I were you I would avoid the `-250px` approach, since you don't have to do this if you just give a `padding: 0px;` to the containing `ul`. That way you don't have to have a `#first` class, and your controls are aligned neatly.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work--the buttons don't get aligned to the left, and the stuff under the div gets messed up. Thanks though!